# Undefined Index: func isset is present

Tags: php

Receiving the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: func in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/select2/func.php on line 23
>   Notice: Undefined index: func in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/select2/func.php on line 67
>   Notice: Undefined index: func in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/select2/func.php on line 114

Here are the offending lines:

Line 23

```
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{
```

Line 67

```
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_2" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
drop_2($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_2($drop_var)
{
```

Line 114

```
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_3" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
drop_3($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_3($drop_var)
{
```

I looked in the existing questions and didn't find an answer where an if statement was attached with the operator &&.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of your condition to this:

```
if(isset($_GET['func']) && $_GET['func'] == "drop_1" )
```

Now you are checking if the 'func' index is set first before using it.

Comment: Thanks very much Ibu.  Seems that we have consensus here.

Answer (score 1):

You have the order of your logical operators backwards. First you need to check to see if the variable is set and then you need to check it's value. If the first check is false then the second one will never happen due to short circuiting which prevents the error message you see.

```
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) {
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_GET['func']) && $_GET['func'] == "drop_1") {
```

Comment: it's always something small isn't it?  Thanks John!